# apache htaccess to nginx rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have these htaccess rules and I want to convert them to nginx. I have tried online converters and different approaches but nothing seems to work. I am curious to see other opinions, to compare with everything I did by now and see if something will work in the end.

Here is the code from the apache .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} HTTP_IS_RETINA [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !@2x
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ $1@2x.$2
# if @2x isn't available fulfill the original request
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)@2x\.(gif|jpg|png)$ $1.$2
```